# UPDATE query to copy from one table to another based on a secondary field

Tags: mysql, sql

I altered my table structure today and created the 'Country' fields/table and I need to perform an UPDATE query to bring everything in line.

I have thousands of records. CityID has been populated with the IDs from the City lookup table since the database was created. CountryID is currently empty as a new field.

I have begun to associate each CityID with a CountryID. For example, New York City's CityID = "25" and the USA's CountryID = "1", so these values are inputted into the **City** table.

I would like to UPDATE Main.CountryID retrospectively, so for any records where Main.CityID = "25", it should automatically insert Main.CountryID = 1

Does that make sense?

My **Main** table:

```
MainID  
Name  
Address etc.  
CityID
CountryID (Empty)
```

My **City** table

```
CityID  
City  
CountryID
```

My **Country** table

```
CountryID  
Country
```

Apologies for protracted question, it's been a long day...

Answer (score 1):

Do an join update of the `Main` table with the `City` table:

```
UPDATE Main a
INNER JOIN City b 
    ON a.CityID = b.CityID
SET a.CountryID = b.CountryID
```

Comment: Nope, because I have 118 separate Cities and around 20 different countries, spread across 1000+ records. I need to update them all in one go, using the 'City' table as reference.

Comment: I updated my answer, your question wording was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

As you have values in City Table update the Main table column on the basis of join with City Table

Try this, i hope this works fine.

```
Update t1
   set t1.CountryID = t2.CountryID
   FROM Main AS t1
   INNER JOIN City AS t2 ON t1.CityID = t2.CityID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I already try it.

```
UPDATE mainid a JOIN city b
    ON a.cityID = b.cityID
SET a.countryID = b.countryID
```

Okay, I will explain it.
if You wanna get countryID based on cityID. You should join table **MainID** with table **cityID** because in that table there is **cityID and countryID**. So, join `mainid a JOIN city b a.cityID = b.cityID` and `set a.countryID = b.countryID`

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.